# App idea for creating a playlist using specific paramters (i.e. mood, genre, tempo) using a specific library set

Tags: api, metadata, spotify

I am looking to create an app for Spotify and I was wondering exactly what metadata we are able to access once we have access to Spotify's APIs. The app that I am trying to create would be a playlist creator using music in my organization's Spotify library and is geared towards a specific community. Our library consists of multiple genres of music with a common theme, and I want to provide users with a way to create playlists with set paramters (i.e. genre, mood, activity, tempo, etc.), but I need a way to essentially "tag" songs in our library. Would this be feasible using Spotify's APIs?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you'll need to supply the tagging yourself. How you do this is up to you. For example, you might have a service running that returns a 'mood' for a given track URI. Creating temporary playlists can be done using the Playlist class.

Have a look at http://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/preview/api/ for the latest API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for the same thing: an API which provides us with genre, mood etc. Here's what I've found http://developer.echonest.com/docs/v4/artist.html#list-terms for the style and mood and http://developer.echonest.com/raw_tutorials/faqs/faq_04.html for the tempo

Echo Nest is acquired by Spotify by the way.